# VLC Icon in Tray Multiple Times

Tags: 12.04, vlc

So, when I start watching a video or something of the like, VLC puts a nice little icon in the tray. The problem is, that when I open and close VLC it keeps adding another nice little icon in the tray.

Here's a SS for example's sake.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to **Tools->Preferences**

[image]

Check the option of “allow only one instance". 
You may want to check the related "Enqueue files in playlist when in one instance mode" too.
Press save.

Comment: Works like a charm. Cheers for that Jasmines

Comment: I recommend also to uncheck show systray, so after use vlc doesnt active occupying memory!