# Ubuntu 20.04 unexpected top bar icon (VLC video player)

Tags: 20.04

1. Ubuntu 20.04
2. VLC from "Ubuntu Software Center"
3. icon of VLC appears at right side among "Gnome shell extension" icons
4. icon remains after VLC has quit
5. icon remains after I uninstall VLC
6. I found no way to remove this icon except re-boot

Answer (score 5):

On a terminal which you can get by the Ctrl+Alt+t key combo run

```
killall -9 vlc
```

Comment: It works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's looks like a bug of 3.0.10+ versions, because I have this on ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 and when I tried 3.0.11 version.
For now, you can reinstall vlc with apt:

```
sudo snap remove vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```

you will get a bit older version but without this bug.
Version which you get depends from your distro:
Ubuntu 20.04 - 3.0.9.2
Ubuntu 18.04 - 3.0.8

Note about bug on 3.0.10 version:
1) Closing vlc via "top bar icon" menu closes vlc and correctly removes icon.
2) If you close vlc by pressing window button when video file opened icon will remain, but closing empty vlc instance or with music doesn't cause this.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem in Ubuntu 20.04 with version 3.0.9.2, it won't close when I exit from topbar icon nor will it open another video, I have to kill -9 it from terminal or reboot

Comment: Yes you are right. I checked it on freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04. Maybe 3.0.8 version would work but I didn't find how to install it via package manager on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: 3.0.9.2 didn't have this problem but something changed from moment of writing answer

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug! but you can remove it with htop.
find it with pressing f4 and typing vlc the press f9 and use sygkill to kill.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that VLC is still running. Uninstalling from the drive may not remove the application from memory.

I have found two solutions:

1. Use System Monitor (GUI) and select and kill the vlc process.
2. Change preferences inside VLC as shown on [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/163207/551485).

Comment: This did the trick, but I had to kill -9 it bc it didn't respond. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems this bug is still in ubuntu 22.04 snap, uninstalling it and reinstall with apt helps here